# Flux of a vector field without the bottom

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

I have to evaluate the flux of the vector field
$$F(x,y,z)=(y^2,x,x^2)$$
through the surface
$$\sigma_{0}\colon z=4-x^2-y^2$$
and above the plane
$$\sigma_{1}\colon z=1$$
(but not to include the bottom).

What I thought was: if $\sigma$ is the surface bounded by the paraboloid and the plane above, so
$$\iint_{\sigma}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS=\iint_{\sigma_{0}}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS+\iint_{\sigma_{1}}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS$$

A parametrization for $\sigma_{0}$ is
$$\sigma_{0}(u,v)=(u,v,1),\quad\forall(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$$
then
$$\frac{\partial\sigma_{1}}{\partial u}\wedge\frac{\partial\sigma_{1}}{\partial v}=(0,0,1)$$
and since
$$F(\sigma_{1})=(v^2,u,u^2)$$
I got
$$\iint_{\sigma_{1}}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS=\iint_{R}u^{2}dudv$$
where $R$ is intersection between $\sigma_{0}$ and $\sigma_{1}$:
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=3\Leftrightarrow u^{2}+v^{2}=3$$
which, in polar coordinates is equivalent to
$$\iint_{\sigma_{1}}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}r^{3}\cos^2(\theta)drd\theta=\frac{9\pi}{4}$$

And since
$$div\vec{F}=0$$
from Gauss' theorem
$$\iint_{\sigma_{0}}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}dS=\iiint_{B}div\vec{F}dV=\iiint_{B}0dV=0$$
Therefore, the flux is $-\dfrac{9\pi}{4}$. Is it correct?

Comment: You'd better check the computation of the flux across the disk. Since $x^2\ge 0$ everywhere on that disk, you will get a positive flux.

Comment: Oh yes, I just realized I didn't write $\cos^{2}\theta$, thanks!

Comment: @TedShifrin is it correct now?

Comment: Not quite. Don't forget that $dA = r\,dr\,d\theta$. And think carefully about your signs. How is the disk oriented as part of the boundary of the solid region?

Comment: @TedShifrin I just corrected it. And the exercise doesn't say anything about the orientation.

Comment: They need to tell you how to orient the paraboloid in order for you to calculate flux.

Comment: If I suppose it's a positive orientation (the normal vector pointing outside), is it correct?

Comment: I believe I should consider the flux of the plane $-9\pi/4$ due to the fact it's pointing to inside $\sigma$.

Comment: I would ordinarily orient the paraboloid with the normal pointing upward, which means the disk at the bottom is oriented downward. Thus, when you subtract, you see that whatever flows *upward* across the disk is what flows *upward* across the paraboloid (since divergence is $0$).